# Csrf token validation failed in OrangeHrm after Apache update to 2.4.27

Tags: php, apache2, csrf, orangehrm

Getting following error while trying to login. I have been tested with most of the browser , yet same error.
[image: OrangeHrm Error]

Running with php 5.6.

Is there any idea , what aspect should i look into to resolve the issue. I have been looked through error logs , but unable to find any hints of this error. Does it something to do with apache or OrangeHrm.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, whoever tried to help, I have been resolved the issue and i think it may helpful for others if have similar issue:

In apache2 the cookie was disable over http and our site does not server https. So, we have to enable cookie over http and it works.

So, from my understanding, if you have similar issue, look your redirect setting as well.